# How does one make screen captures with a shadow?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

How to do beautiful print screens, with shadows on the border, like this image?

[image: Screenshot with shadow]

Is the shadows automatic? A Mac tool? Do I need to manipulate the image in other programs like Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: +1 surprisingly i found out that not many people knew about this nifty feature in Mac OS X

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, you do not need to. This feature is built into Mac OS X.

To do this, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> then press <kbd>Space</kbd>. The selector will then change into a camera icon, and you can take a screenshot of the selected window with a shadow.

[image: screenshot of screenshotting]

(I couldn't capture the camera icon)

End result:
[image: end product]

Comment: +1 - I didn't know about the `space` option. Man, that's an ugly camera icon.

Comment: To make it easier, the spacebar doesn't have to be pressed right in the sequence like that: Cmd-Shift-4 [release] gives you the crosshairs, after which you can press and release the spacebar.

Comment: That's a lot of junk you have on your Desktop.

Comment: Extra modifiers: Ctrl, capture to clipboard, Cmd-N in Preview will create a new window containing the screenshot; Option, eliminate the drop shadow

Comment: You can get the camera icon by capturing a screen recording using Quicktime. It has to be the whole screen, though. Then grab a screenshot of a frame from the movie. If you try to just record a portion of the screen, then there's an invisible window floating above all others and when you hit Space, it'll highlight the whole screen in blue.

Comment: Also, note that the file type of the screenshot must be PNG. The shadow will not show up properly if it is a JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I prefer ***NOT*** to capture with the shadow at all. There is a command line procedure for suppressing the shadows, but you can accomplish the same thing through the GUI of [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html).

[image]

Install TinkerTool and then under its "General" tab, un-check the box next to "Include shadow when capturing window".

Comment: TinkerTool basically does just `defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true`. You can disable shadows for single screenshots with `screencapture -i -W -o`. (`-i` = interactive, `-W` = window selection mode.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. While I can certainly perform command-line operations, I highly value tools like TinkerTool, MacPilot, Cocktail and DeepVacuum, which can do all sorts of command-line functions for me in a nice, simple GUI that organizes many parameters of many applications together in one place.

Comment: You can also disable the shadow by holding ⌥alt when you click to take the screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

The shadows aren't automatic.  There is a free tool called [ImageShadowAdder](http://boredzo.org/imageshadowadder/) that can do these for you.

Comment: The shadows are automatic if you press space and capture just a window.